# strange review - "skip" as only option

Tags: bug

Has anyone [image]been presented with such a review?

The review link: https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/489387

Comment: Ping me in chat if you notice more than 1. Also, can you provide a link to the review task?

Comment: Will do - the link is in my question now - sorry for having forgotten :-)

Comment: So the reason no actions can be taken on that post is because it was merged (and thus locked). However the fact that it is still being shown as an audit is definitely a bug.

Comment: Ah, you think thats an audit - well in that case its an esay one :-)

Comment: Yes. The timeline says it was activated as an audit on Nov. 11.